# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Speech Recognition is not available on this system. SAPI and Speech Recognition engines cannot be found

Tags: c#, web-services, web-applications, iis-7, speech-recognition

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with visual Studio 2010.

I have installed the Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime v10.2 and the en-US language packages.

I created a Web Service (Web Application) using Microsoft.Speech. In my test the Web Service receives a string and simulates the recognition based on some grammar rules.

When I run it in Visual Studio using the ASP.NET Development Server, it works correctly without problems.

I then go to IIs and create a Virtual directory pointing to it. When I try to call the web method I get this error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Speech Recognition is not available on this system. SAPI and Speech Recognition engines cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer..ctor(RecognizerType type)
   at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.Initialize(RecognizerInfo recognizerInfo)
   at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine..ctor(CultureInfo culture)
   at VoiceCommand.SimulateVoiceCommand(String command) in c:\Development\Visual Studio 2010\VoiceCommandWebService\VoiceCommandWS\App_Code\VoiceCommand.cs:line 35
```

I don't know what is the difference since I am running it in the same machine. Could it be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some feedback from a Microsoft Forum.

When using the *Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime* it will run properly in a development client OS like Windows 7, but to run it in a production setting it needs to be in a Windows Server OS.

I tested the same Web Service in Windows Server 2008 and it worked.

Comment: I don't see that behavior on my machine. I am running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit with visual Studio 2010. I have installed the Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime v10.2 and the en-US language packages. My app under ASP.NET works fine in the dev environment and when running under IIS. I can't explain why we see different results. From our superficial descriptions I see the only difference as 32-bit OS vs 64.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure if the 32/64 difference would be affecting it

Comment: Just to add some more here. I reconfigured my local IIS so the app pool rung in 32bit and the web service started working (after a quick security issue change).